# MultiBrowser Compatibility

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem, and have done quite a bit of research and can't seem to find anything that works

I have a web application (with multiple Master Pages being used) that works fine in IE7/8/9 (If I remember correctly). However, in IE10/11 and now Edge, have compatibility issues as well as Chrome and FireFox.

I need to make what ever changes(even if it means I need to do it on every master page or preferably to the Web.Config) to allow the entire application to work on any browser. I cant make the changes to every page as there are just way too many pages.

If anyone is able to help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you have to be a able to describe what isn't working correctly in the newer versions of IE and chrome and firefox. Do they simply look different, are they non functioning. Please try to describe what exactly isn't working well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - perhaps I should have given an example :) So, for example, we are using an input field that a datepicker is linked to(datepicker.js), so In IE8 for example, if we click on it, then a datepicker pops up and you can select your date - but in IE10+ and the other browsers the datepicker does not popup. Hope this makes sense

Comment: do you have the exact line of code causing the problem?  I use multiple master pages and can view the code on multiple browsers.  Hence there must be specific code in your pages causing the issue.

Comment: @user2298585 include the datepicker code in your post

Comment: I was running through the code now before you posted and noticed that the Developer who did this previously actually used the wrong name for the datepicker within the javascript functions that was populating hiddenfield values... So in this case it actually does not seem to be a compatibility issue.... However, is there anything specific I would need to know about cross browser compatibility ? Thanks for your time guys.. bit of a waste of time in this case, but I appreciate the replies

Comment: You are 100% correct. In this case it was actually the code and not a compatibility issue. I automatically assumed that it was a compatibility issue when it worked on IE and not any other browser....I am sure somewhere along the line I will pick up a true compatibility issue when it comes to the "look and feel" when the HTML portions are no longer valid in newer versions... thanks!

Comment: Asp.net renders html and javascript. It also makes it possible to plug server code into those two. Just use jQuery to avoid any browser compatibility issues. You may use third party server controls that are not designed to work on certain browsers. Anyways, in its current form your question is too broad. Please narrow it.

Comment: So something I picked up which I can only see as a compatibility issue between the different browsers. Take a label that has no text, in IE it holds an empty space where the label is, but in the other browsers it doesnt, it is as if it does not recognize the label when there is no text ? Below is the label :    <asp:Label ID="ExceptionDetails" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="errormsg" Height="16px"></asp:Label>